# Detect width using Javascript for a navigation bar

Tags: javascript

I have the code below which detects the width and applies inline which works great but I would like it to put the width onto the `<a>` instead of the `<li>`

Does anyone have any insight on this please?

```
$('.navbar-nav li').width(function () {
    return $(this).find("a").parent().width()
});
```

Comment: change .navbar-nav li to the a tag then?

Comment: I did try this but seems to disable the code, don't think it's that straight forward.

Comment: could you perhaps do a jsfiddle example of what you currently have so we can reproduce and help with a solution specific to you?

Comment: Yes sure, see attached: https://jsfiddle.net/L6g90mLn/1/

Comment: I get particularly close with this fiddle but issue is here it sizes them all to the first one: https://jsfiddle.net/L6g90mLn/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your jsfiddle (thanks for that), this is the solution I came up with:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').each(function(index){
    $(this).width(function () {
        return $(this).width();
    });
});
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6g90mLn/7/